# how to correctly get (axios) by UUID , ReactJs NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

currently i am logging in,
I am in my profile, and here I would like to display my name.

the following code works correctly, only it shows me all the use registered in my database.

and I would only like to be able to display the correct name which corresponds to the UID in my database

How can I fix this issue?

that is my get and return

```js
class Profile  extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[]
    };
  }

  getRandom = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://joke.fr/api/profil"
    );

    this.setState({ data: res.data })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom()
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
        {this.state.data.map(data => <p>{data.name}</p>)}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

that is my route is bdd

```js
app.get('/api/profil', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * from profil' , (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la récupération des employés');
    } else {
      console.log(results);
      return res.json(results);
    }
  });
});
```

and last one is my BDD schéma.

```
{
  "id": 62,
  "name": "neff",
  "uid": "dycjibu96zgmzc0KpGAqxKiUsMu2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need another parameter in your app.get. I suppose when user logged in to your app, you store their UID. If that's the case, you can use:

```
app.get('api/profil/:id', (req, res) => {
        const userId = req.params.id
        connection.query(`SELECT * from profil WHERE id = ${userId}` , (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la récupération des employés');
          } else {
             console.log(results);
             return res.json(results);
          }
       });
})
```

But I would recommend something like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to sanitise your SQL request though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are logged in then probably you have the UUID or name in the browser saved in the local storage (this is the simplest approach). This means on your backend you should send a `GET` request to get 1 profile based on the UUID.

### Server Side Code

```js
app.get('/api/profil/:name', (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;

  connection.query(`SELECT * from profil where name=${name}`, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la récupération des employés');
    } else {
      // This should be an object
      console.log(results); // This should be an object like {"id": 62, "name": "authUser"}
      return res.json(results);
    }
  });
});
```

### Client Side Code

```js
class Profile  extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userProfile: null
    };
  }

  getUserProfile = async (userName) => {
    // Get the profile by passing the id to the URL.
    // Side note, you should handle errors here but for simplicity lets skip it.

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://joke.fr/api/profil/${userName}`
    );

    // res.data should be an object like {"id": 62, "name": "authUser"}
    this.setState({ userProfile: res.data });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // You should have the id of the user after login
    // Let me assume you stored it in localstorage
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (user) {
      const { id, name } = JSON.parse(user);
      // You can skip the localstorage part if you store the user's details in a different way and jump here by passing the ID/name to this function
      this.getUserProfile(name);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { userProfile } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {userProfile ? userProfile.name : "No user name"}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: hi I have a 404 error , 
on postman , 
and on my server I only have "No user name" and 
how can i check if my UUID and well in my local storage. ?

Comment: ok i checked for the local storoage ,  
I do have a trick on the other hand not UUID name is  "authUser" because I use FIREBASE does that change anything?

Comment: Can you paste your current code in a github gist.github.com/new ? I will debug the issue faster to understand why you get the 404. And send me the URL to the request you are sending via postman.

Comment: I updated the code so you can send name instead of id, there basically isn't much difference, you just have to change the express url, sql query on your server, and data you send from the client side.

Comment: ok , that is my gist https://gist.github.com/Neffou/8d4c2020b125b9884ff0b165e5f12b3d,
do not panic when you go to see the mess ^^ I am a beginner

Comment: i have same probleme error 404 https://gist.github.com/Neffou/ed2e33a2da086311b18f03a295bda234 that is route

Comment: you have any tips ?

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code, I don't know why you are making the request to `https://joke.fr`, is your express server already deployed to that domain? Locally this code should work correctly. if you sent a get request to `http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/api/cartebleuuser/230844345`